# Order BY in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

In my SQL statement, need to parse a title field so I can order by the integers. Basically, just extract the integers into a new field and order on that field.

the data in the title field looks like the following (WRONG):

```
TT TEST 750-1
TT TEST 80-1
TT TEST 1 UU 25-1
TT TEST 1 UU 420-1
TT TEST 1 UU 55-46
TT TEST 1 UU 600-8-10
TT TEST 1 UU 608-20
TT TEST 1 UU 750-1
```

after order by (CORRECT)

```
TT TEST 80-1
TT TEST 750-1
TT TEST 1 UU 25-1
TT TEST 1 UU 55-46
TT TEST 1 UU 420-1
TT TEST 1 UU 600-8-10
TT TEST 1 UU 608-20
TT TEST 1 UU 750-1
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's not completely clear which part of the field you wish to sort by. Can you update the question with expected output based on the input you have shown?

Comment: Also with the - in there are you planning on removing that as well? So it is only the numeric part of the title that you want to sort?

Comment: Are entries always of the form "Test Title AA xyz-ab"? And you need to order by xyz or by xyzab?

Comment: what's the maximum number of hyphens allowed, if there is a limit?

Comment: Your example doesn't follow the rule you've given. If the sort is based on the last value first, then the rows starting `TT TEST 1 UU` should be ordered with all the rows ending `-1` first

Comment: Should the rightmost values be sorted numerically (20 > 3) or alphabetically (20 < 3)?

Comment: In rows with different numbers of hyphens, is the rightmost value always compared, or should they be compared by position? e.g. would `111-11-1` come before or after `111-10`?

Comment: Hi ed, thanks for your feedback. I stand corrected. raze2dust query is sooo close to what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the PATINDEX function:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SubString(REPLACE(Title,'-',''),
    PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REPLACE(Title,'-','')),
    Len(REPLACE(Title,'-',''))) 
    AS INT)
AS [Title Number],*
FROM [Your table-name here] 
ORDER BY [Title Number]
```

Edit: Will work with hyphen now.

Note: Will not work if the Non-numeric part of the title has numbers or has a hyphen ('-').

Comment: The solution you gave is just a little off...here's the sort it produced: <pre> (1)TT TEST 1 UU 25-1 (2)TT TEST 1 UU 420-1 (3)TT TEST 1 UU 55-46 (4)TT TEST 1 UU 600-8-10 (5)TT TEST 1 UU 608-20 (6)TT TEST 1 UU 750-1 (7)TT TEST 750-1 (8)TT TEST 80-1 <code>

Comment: I'd say you probably have the information to fix it now gates.

Comment: Yup, as I said, if the non-index part has numbers (Like 1 in your case), then it won't work. You can try inverting the Title (Use REVERSE()), extracting the numeric index, then invert back the index and cast it to INT and then sort. Let me know if  you were able to do it that way..

Comment: Probably make a stored proc and use temporary tables to do this so that the script looks less messy..

Comment: Even better, Invert the Title. ('TT TEST 1 UU 25-1' becomes '1-52 UU 1 TSET TT'), get the substring upto the first space (i.e, '1-52'), replace the hyphen('-') with empty char ('') (becomes '152'), invert back the string (becomes '251') and cast this as [Title number] (INT)) and sort..